# How to pass attributes to chef in local mode

Tags: chef-infra

I want to override a default attribute that I have defined in my default attributes file in the cookbook:

*/attributes/default.rb*:

```
default[:server][:name] = "test"
default[:server][:port] = "8080"
```

I am running `chef-client` in local mode: `chef-client -z -j node.json`

with this *node.json*:

```
{
  "name": "mycookbook",
  "default__attributes": { 
    "server": {
      "name": "myCustomName"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[mycookbook]"
  ]
}
```

The cookbook is running without complaining but the attribute `server.name` is never replaced with the value I'm passing in my *node.json* file.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**:

Recipe */recipes/default.rb*:

```
template 'C:\my.properties' do
  source 'my.properties.erb'
end
```

Template */templates/default/my.properties.erb*:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<%= node[:server][:name] %>:<%= node[:server][:port] %>;databaseName=test
```

Comment: I'm not using json files usually but I'm pretty sure there's only one `_` between default and attribute, here you have 2.

Comment: And in fact doing a node show in json format, there's no default_attribute entry, just default, so remove __attributes and this should work as expected.

Comment: @Tensibai using only `default` does not work either. The attribute is still taken from the _default.rb_ file

Comment: Should work according to [the doc](https://docs.chef.io/nodes.html#attribute-precedence)

Comment: Show your recipe code, there's probably something in the recipe which is wrong (mainly I think about accessing node.default instead of node.

Comment: @Tensibai I've added the contents of my recipe and template

Comment: Sorry, seems you can't set anything else than normal attributes into a json node object (default and override are computed and then merge with the normal level), just remove the default level ([documentation](https://docs.chef.io/chef_solo.html#attributes)) to give it a try